# How To: Caliburn.Micro.Autofac and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, autofac, caliburn.micro

Is there and example, tutorial or anything that shows how to use Caliburn.Micro.Autofac with Windows Phone?

I created a basic application with Caliburn.Micro only, and that runs fine. Then I decided to use Caliburn.Micro.Autofac, so I derived my Bootstrapper from `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper` and called `base.Configure()` inside the Bootstrapper `Configure()` method. Now wen I ran the application I get "The type 'AppBootstrapper' was not found." exception.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bootstrapper I wrote for a WP7 project. It's based on `Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper` but fixes some bugs.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : PhoneBootstrapper
{
    private IContainer container;

    protected void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // put any custom bindings here
    }

    #region Standard Autofac/Caliburn.Micro Bootstrapper

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //  configure container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //  register phone services
        var caliburnAssembly = AssemblySource.Instance.Union(new[] { typeof(IStorageMechanism).Assembly }).ToArray();
        //  register IStorageMechanism implementors
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(caliburnAssembly)
          .Where(type => typeof(IStorageMechanism).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                         && !type.IsAbstract
                         && !type.IsInterface)
          .As<IStorageMechanism>()
          .SingleInstance();

        //  register IStorageHandler implementors
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(caliburnAssembly)
          .Where(type => typeof(IStorageHandler).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                         && !type.IsAbstract
                         && !type.IsInterface)
          .As<IStorageHandler>()
          .SingleInstance();

        // The constructor of these services must be called
        // to attach to the framework properly.
        var phoneService = new PhoneApplicationServiceAdapter(RootFrame);
        var navigationService = new FrameAdapter(RootFrame, false);

        builder.Register<IPhoneContainer>(c => new AutofacPhoneContainer(c)).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterInstance<INavigationService>(navigationService).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterInstance<IPhoneService>(phoneService).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register<IEventAggregator>(c => new EventAggregator()).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register<IWindowManager>(c => new WindowManager()).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register<IVibrateController>(c => new SystemVibrateController()).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register<ISoundEffectPlayer>(c => new XnaSoundEffectPlayer()).SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<StorageCoordinator>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<TaskController>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        //  allow derived classes to add to the container
        ConfigureContainer(builder);

        //  build the container
        container = builder.Build();

        //  start services
        container.Resolve<StorageCoordinator>().Start();
        container.Resolve<TaskController>().Start();

        //  add custom conventions for the phone
        AddCustomConventions();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        object instance;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            if (container.TryResolve(service, out instance))
                return instance;
        }
        else
        {
            if (container.TryResolveNamed(key, service, out instance))
                return instance;
        }
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", key ?? service.Name));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(service)) as IEnumerable<object>;
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.InjectProperties(instance);
    }

    private static void AddCustomConventions()
    {
        ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<Pivot>(Pivot.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged").ApplyBinding =
            (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
            {
                if (ConventionManager
                    .GetElementConvention(typeof(ItemsControl))
                    .ApplyBinding(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention))
                {
                    ConventionManager
                        .ConfigureSelectedItem(element, Pivot.SelectedItemProperty, viewModelType, path);
                    ConventionManager
                        .ApplyHeaderTemplate(element, Pivot.HeaderTemplateProperty, viewModelType);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };

        ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<Panorama>(Panorama.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged").ApplyBinding =
            (viewModelType, path, property, element, convention) =>
            {
                if (ConventionManager
                    .GetElementConvention(typeof(ItemsControl))
                    .ApplyBinding(viewModelType, path, property, element, convention))
                {
                    ConventionManager
                        .ConfigureSelectedItem(element, Panorama.SelectedItemProperty, viewModelType, path);
                    ConventionManager
                        .ApplyHeaderTemplate(element, Panorama.HeaderTemplateProperty, viewModelType);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**EDIT** I have created a fork of Caliburn.Micro.Autofac and fixed the issue on GitHub. Hopefully the pull request will be accepted and this will become part of the main repository.

For now, you can access the bootstrapper, and AutofacPhoneContainer from here - https://github.com/distantcam/Caliburn.Micro.Autofac/tree/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Autofac-WP7

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be honest, I didn't have chance to try your code, but did a fast comparison between your code and the original Caliburn.Micro.Autofac. Unfortunately, I didn't quite understand the bugs you're referring to and the reason behind the changes you did. Appreciate if you can explain that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK the main fix is where the PhoneApplicationServiceAdapter and FrameAdapter are created first, and then added into the Autofac container. If they are not initialized then Caliburn Micro doesn't work properly.

Comment: Do you have an update for caliburn micro 1.3 and new version of autofac? Caliburn.Micro.Autofac is only 1.2.1

Comment: What is AutofacPhoneContainer? I can't see it

Comment: Caliburn.Micro.Autofac was updated to work with Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1. See here https://github.com/dbuksbaum/Caliburn.Micro.Autofac

Comment: Cameron, yes it has new version but the code for WP7 is the same, no changes since 1.3. I've checked. He even didn't fixed that bag you pointed in this answer (about calling ctors of PhoneApplicationServiceAdapter and FrameAdapter. I even don't tell about implementing IPhoneContainer in any way.
I am in the way of implementing of IPhoneContainer but I'm curious how you implemented AutofacPhoneContainer using syntax: c => new AutofacPhoneContainer(c). If you are using IContainerContex in this class you should use like: c => new AutofacPhoneContainer(c.Resolve<IComponentContext>())

Comment: @MikeEshva Yeah, I didn't take a good look at the update. :P I've updated the answer to include my fork with the fix, and missing AutofacPhoneContainer.

Comment: Thank you very much, Cameron! I go to check it out.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Where is the best place to discus your implementation? I guess it has some problems.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Unfortunately your current realization doesn't work in scenario of store object state nor using StoreHandler<T>.Property() nor using StoreHandler<T>.EntireGraph. The IPhoneContainer implementation used for the EntireGraph scenario. The root of problem in your code from my experience is you don't raise IPhoneContainer.Activated event for objects that should support support store mechanism. Calling this event for such objects (ViewModels, Models) solves this problem.
Anyway you are tough on Autofac and this is my major problem for the moment. I'll try to make my version.

Comment: @MikeEshva Any further discussion is probably best done on my fork on GitHub.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland with any IoC you use with CM on the phone you have to do the stuff in PhoneContainer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651735/intercept-ninject-instance-activation

Comment: @MikeEshva Fixed in my fork. Let me know if there's any further problems.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland Thank you Cameron! I'm currently busy with another project. So have no time to check it out. Another problem I can point but cannot explain in detail is that EntireGraph doesn't work at least in your prior version. Probably your way to implement RegisterWithPhoneService is wrong. It should be a named registration, it should be a fresh new instance before caling this method and just singleton after. It is the way I've understood it. I've coded it but it doesn't work yet because of order of invocation of framework methods. Sorry no time to dig further. And thank you for effort

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a proper version (in my opinion) of Caliburn.Micro.Autofac for Windows Phone. You can download it and test project from [my blog](http://mike.eshva.ru/dev/windows-phone-caliburn.micro-autofac). The blog post is in Russian but you'll find the link to ZIP file in the top of the post. The code is too big to post here, so please take from the blog. I've send this to David Buksbaum (the author of Caliburn.Micro.Autofac). Hope he will incorporate it into his code base soon.

**UPDATE**

What is fixed:

1. Components realizing IPhoneService and INavigationService services must be instantiated before registering in container.
2. Realized component implementing IPhoneContainer. Without it you can't use Autofac in Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: You might want to describe what you have fixed instead of just referring to your blog.